# How to check rate limit in streaming api in twitter

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I have managed to get the live tweets for a certain keyword. So far so good, I tried to add some `RateLimitStatusListener` in case I reach rate limit.

The problem is, never gets called. Even if I reach rate limit it does not get called. I could not figure it out.
My intention is, if I get rate limit error do some error handling. Despite that is there any other way to check whether rate limit has been reached?

```
public final class PrintSampleStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {

        TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance();
        StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatus(Status status) {
                System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {
                System.out.println("Got a status deletion notice id:" + statusDeletionNotice.getStatusId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {
                System.out.println("Got track limitation notice:" + numberOfLimitedStatuses);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {
                System.out.println("Got scrub_geo event userId:" + userId + " upToStatusId:" + upToStatusId);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStallWarning(StallWarning warning) {
                System.out.println("Got stall warning:" + warning);
            }

            @Override
            public void onException(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        twitterStream.addRateLimitStatusListener( new RateLimitStatusListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRateLimitStatus( RateLimitStatusEvent event ) {
                System.out.println("Limit["+event.getRateLimitStatus().getLimit() + "], Remaining[" +event.getRateLimitStatus().getRemaining()+"]");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRateLimitReached( RateLimitStatusEvent event ) {
                System.out.println("Limit["+event.getRateLimitStatus().getLimit() + "], Remaining[" +event.getRateLimitStatus().getRemaining()+"]");
            }
        } );

        FilterQuery filterQuery = new FilterQuery();
        String[] query = {"#WorldCup2014"};
        filterQuery.track(query);

        twitterStream.addListener(listener);
        twitterStream.filter(filterQuery); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rate limits you are mentioning applies only for twitter rest api, not streaming api. In streaming, there is no need to add code like that, because limitations are handled in a different way:

> You will be streamed 1% of total volume

Which means you will get 1% of what you are tracking or following in streaming api.

> How are rate limits determined on the Streaming API?
>
> The public streaming APIs cap the number of messages sent to your
>   client to a small fraction of the total volume of Tweets at any given
>   moment.
>
> The sample hose, as documented in
>   https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json, delivers a random
>   sampling of all Tweets at a volume equal to the public streaming cap.
>
> Filtered streams return all matching Tweets up to a volume equal to
>   the streaming cap. If there are more tweets that would match your
>   criteria, you'll be streamed a rate limit message indicating how many
>   tweets were not delivered.

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/2907

Comment: if we don't include any filter, will it give us the 1% of the total tweet volume?